# Using imshow() to create higher quality hist2d

Tags: python, image, image-processing, matplotlib

I am playing around with volumetric data and I am trying to project a "cosmic web" like image.

I pretty much create a file path and open the data with a module that opens hdf5 files. The `x` and `y` values are denoted by indexing from a the file `gas_pos` and the histogram is weighted by different properties,  `gas_density` in this case:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap
from matplotlib.ticker import LogFormatter 


cmap = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('mycmap', ['black', 'steelblue', 'mediumturquoise', 'darkslateblue'])

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

H = ax.hist2d(gas_pos[:,0]/0.7, gas_pos[:,1]/0.7, bins=500, cmap=cmap, norm=matplotlib.colors.LogNorm(), weights=gas_density);

cb = fig.colorbar(H[3], ax=ax, shrink=0.8, pad=0.01, orientation="horizontal", label=r'$ \rho\ [M_{\odot}\ \mathrm{kpc}^{-3}]$')
ax.tick_params(axis=u'both', which=u'both',length=0)
ax.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
ax.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)

plt.show()
```

giving me this:

[image]

which is nice, but I want to up the quality and remove the grainyness of it. When I try `imshow` interpolation:

```
cmap = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('mycmap', ['black', 'steelblue', 'mediumturquoise', 'darkslateblue'])

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
H = ax.hist2d(gas_pos[:,0]/0.7, gas_pos[:,1]/0.7, bins=500, cmap=cmap, norm=matplotlib.colors.LogNorm(), weights=gas_density);

ax.tick_params(axis=u'both', which=u'both',length=0)
ax.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
ax.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)

im = ax.imshow(H[0], cmap=cmap, interpolation='sinc', norm=matplotlib.colors.LogNorm())
cb = fig.colorbar(H[3], ax=ax, shrink=0.8, pad=0.01, orientation="horizontal", label=r'$ \rho\ [M_{\odot}\ \mathrm{kpc}^{-3}]$')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Am I using this incorrectly? or is there something better I can use to modify the pixelation?

If anyone is wanting to play with my data, I will upload the data later on today!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `interpolation='sinc'` is indeed a good method to smoothen a plot. Others would e.g. be `"gaussian"`, `"bicubic"` or `"spline16"`.

The problem you observe is that the `imshow` plot is plotted on top of the `hist2d` plot and thus takes its axes limits. Those limits seem to be smaller than the number of points in the imshow plot and therefore you only see part of the total data.

The solution is either not to plot the hist2d plot at all or at least to plot it into another subplot or figure.

Pursuing the first idea, you would calculate your histogram without plotting it, using `numpy.histogram2d`

```
H, xedges, yedges = np.histogram2d(gas_pos[:,0]/0.7, gas_pos[:,1]/0.7,
                                   bins=500, weights=gas_density)
im = ax.imshow(H.T, cmap=cmap, interpolation='sinc', norm=matplotlib.colors.LogNorm())
```

I would also recommend reading the [`numpy.histogram2d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram2d.html) documentation, which includes an example of plotting the histogram output in matplotlib.

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably want to set `interpolation='None'` in the call to `imshow`, instead of `interpolation='sinc'`

Comment: Thank you for answering. But when changing the interpolation to 'None', I get very large pixels from imshow. Is the normal?

Comment: Are you maybe zoomed right in? You shouldn't necessarily get extra large pixels when using 'None', unless there's fewer pixels there.